# Access structure members inside a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I have a structure

```
struct packet
{
    int src_ip;
    int dest_ip;
    int src_port;
    int dest_port;
    int protocol;
};
```

A cuda kernel is as follows:

```
__global__ 
void GPU(struct packet * packets,int * gpu_action)
{
    int i;
    i = (int) packets[6]->src_ip;
}
```

main function is as follows:

```
int main ()
{

    int * gpu_action;
    struct packet * gpu_packets;
    struct packet * cpu_gpu_packets;
    int * action;

    action = (int *)malloc(TOTAL_PACKETS*sizeof(int));
    cpu_gpu_packets = (struct packet *)malloc(TOTAL_PACKETS*sizeof(struct packet));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_action,TOTAL_PACKETS*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_packets,TOTAL_PACKETS*sizeof(struct packet));
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_packets,cpu_gpu_packets,TOTAL_PACKETS*sizeof(struct packet),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    GPU<<<1,1>>>(gpu_packets,gpu_action);

}
```

When I am compiling it using nvcc, I get errors and warnings.
It gives me a error "**expression must be a pointer to a complete object type**"
at the following point

```
    i = packets[6]->src_ip;
```

Is any thing wrong in the syntax ??
The above code works fine with host functions but not with cuda __global__ functions.

Comment: In the future, please pay more attention to code formatting when you post a question. If you are expecting people to read a large amount of your code in a question, please make the effort to format it so that it is easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong operator to access elements in your array of packets.

Change:

```
i = (int) packets[6]->src_ip;
                   ^^^^
```

to:

```
i = packets[6].src_ip;
             ^^^
```

Also, don't try to fix compile errors by adding random casts - it's usually not the right solution - always try to understand the underlying problem and fix it properly.

Comment: I changed it but still the same error, well thanks for the reply

Comment: Are you *sure* you changed `->` to `.` ?

Comment: And your kernel code can see the complete declaration of `struct packet`, i.e. you've #included the relevant header, or it's declared in the same source file ? (You haven't just anonymously declared `struct packet;` in the kernel source file in order to "fix" an earlier compile error ?)

Comment: When I take your code, build a complete app out of it, and only make the change suggested by Paul R, it compiles correctly, with no errors (only warnings),  as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/QwScY9Jp).  If you're still having trouble, it's because of something you haven't told us or shown us about how you are arranging your code or compiling.